# Exception when i'm saving data in mysql

Tags: php

I have problem with save data in mysql.

I have such a class to connect with databases:

```
class Db
{
    private $_hostname;
    private $_database;
    private $_username;
    private $_password;
    private $_port;
    private $_pdo;
    private $_sQuery;
    private $_bConnected = false;
    private $_parameters;
    private $_config;
    private $_psException;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_config = Registry::register("Core\Utilities\Config");
        $this->_psException = new PsException();

        $this->_hostname = $this->_config->db_host;
        $this->_database = $this->_config->db_db;
        $this->_username = $this->_config->db_user;
        $this->_password = $this->_config->db_pass;
        $this->_port = $this->_config->db_port;

        $this->Connect($this->_hostname, $this->_database, $this->_username, $this->_password, $this->_port);
        $this->_parameters = array();
    }


    private function Connect($hostname, $database, $username, $password, $port)
    {

        try {
            $options = array(\PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
            $this->_pdo = new \PDO("mysql:host={$hostname};dbname={$database};port={$port};charset=utf8", $username, $password, $options);

            $this->_pdo->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $this->_pdo->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, \PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $this->_pdo->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, true);
            $this->_pdo->query('SET NAMES utf8');
            $this->_bConnected = true;
        } catch (PDOException $ex) {
            $this->_psException->registerError("Failed to connect to the database: " . $ex->getMessage());
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->_psException->registerError("Failed to connect to the database: " . $e->getCode() . "." . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }


    public function CloseConnection()
    {
        $this->_pdo = null;
    }


    private function Init($query, $parameters = "")
    {
        if (!$this->_bConnected) {
            $this->Connect();
        }
        try {
            $this->_sQuery = $this->_pdo->prepare($query);

            $this->bindMore($parameters);
            if (!empty($this->_parameters)) {
                foreach ($this->_parameters as $param) {
                    $parameters = explode("\x7F", $param);
                    $this->_sQuery->bindParam($parameters[0], $parameters[1]);
                }
            }
            $this->success = $this->_sQuery->execute();
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $this->ExceptionLog($e->getMessage(), $query);
        }
        $this->_parameters = array();
    }


    public function bind($para, $value)
    {
        $this->_parameters[sizeof($this->_parameters)] = ":" . $para . "\x7F" . ($value);
    }

    public function bindMore($parray)
    {
        if (empty($this->_parameters) && is_array($parray)) {
            $columns = array_keys($parray);
            foreach ($columns as $i => &$column) {
                $this->bind($column, $parray[$column]);
            }
        }
    }

    public function query($query, $params = null, $fetchmode = \PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
    {
        $query = trim($query);
        $this->Init($query, $params);
        $rawStatement = explode(" ", $query);

        $statement = strtolower($rawStatement[0]);

        if ($statement === 'select' || $statement === 'show') {
            return $this->_sQuery->fetchAll($fetchmode);
        } elseif ($statement === 'insert' || $statement === 'update' || $statement === 'delete') {
            return $this->_sQuery->rowCount();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public function lastInsertId()
    {
        return $this->_pdo->lastInsertId();
    }


    public function column($query, $params = null)
    {
        $this->Init($query, $params);
        $Columns = $this->_sQuery->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_NUM);

        $column = null;
        foreach ($Columns as $cells) {
            $column[] = $cells[0];
        }
        return $column;

    }

    public function row($query, $params = null, $fetchmode = \PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
    {
        $this->Init($query, $params);
        return $this->_sQuery->fetch($fetchmode);
    }

    public function single($query, $params = null)
    {
        $this->Init($query, $params);
        return $this->_sQuery->fetchColumn();
    }

    private function ExceptionLog($message, $sql = "")
    {
        $message .= 'Unhandled Exception. $message';
        if (!empty($sql)) {
            $message .= "\r\nQuery SQL : " . $sql;
        }
        $this->_psException->registerError($message);
    }
}
```

and the method to write:

```
$queryValue["enable"] = $dataValues['enable'];
$queryValue["number"] = $dataValues['number'];
$queryValue["description"] = $dataValues['description'];
$queryValue["date"] = $dataValues['date'];
$queryValue["visible_on_the_front"] = $dataValues['visible_on_the_front'];
$queryValue["id_category_page"] = $dataValues['id_category_page'];
$queryValue["visible_on_the_front2"] = $dataValues['visible_on_the_front2'];
$this->_db->query("INSERT INTO psGalleryCategories  (visible_on_the_front2, id_category_page, visible_on_the_front, date, description, enable, number) VALUES (:visible_on_the_front2, :id_category_page, :visible_on_the_front, :date, :description, :enable, :number);", $queryValue);
```

When he writes such a string of characters:

```
'';fwefewfpew'f'wef'wefew.''fewvdsniu*&&^&^@^7ef125e2'""''
```

I have error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'f'wef'wefew.''fewvdsniu*&&^&^@^7ef125e2''' at line 1 in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/um/apps/core/utilities/DbClass.php:78 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/um/apps/core/utilities/DbClass.php(78): PDOStatement->execute() #1 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/um/apps/core/utilities/DbClass.php(139): Core\Utilities\Db->Init('SELECT COUNT(ti...', NULL) #2 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/um/apps/core/models/ModelClass.php(24): Core\Utilities\Db->row('SELECT COUNT(ti...') #3 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/um/apps/backend/models/GalleryModel.php(230): Core\Models\Model->createSeoUrl(''';fwefewfpew'f...', 'title_pl', 'psGalleryCatego...') #4 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/um/apps/backend/controllers/GalleryList.php(14 in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/um/apps/core/utilities/DbClass.php on line 78
```

How to fix this error?

I do not have any problems with normal string. Problem is with combination ',/, "", etc (special characters).

Please help me.

Comment: Did you write that `Db` class? I'm just wondering about the purpose of the `foreach` loop in the `Init` method. I know it's to bind parameters, but since you are passing an associative array, you can just do `$this->success = $this->_sQuery->execute($parameters);`. In any case, I feel there is a possible problem in the binding logic. Try debugging there, see if passing the params to `execute()` works.

Comment: I do not know how to do it :( Will you help me? I've been fighting this since yesterday and I do not know :( Yes, this is a binding problem

Comment: I make this:print_r($this->_sQuery);  $this->success = $this->_sQuery->execute(); and I have result: PDOStatement Object ( [queryString] => SELECT COUNT(title_pl) AS count FROM psGalleryCategories WHERE title_pl = ''';fwefewfpew'f'wef'wefew.''fewvdsniu*&&^&^@^7ef125e2''; )

Comment: When I make this: print_r($this->_sQuery); I have:

Comment: result: PDOStatement Object ( [queryString] => SELECT COUNT(title_pl) AS count FROM psGalleryCategories WHERE title_pl = ''';fwefewfpew'f'wef'wefew.''fewvdsniu*&&^&^@^7ef125e2''; )  - here is too many '''

Comment: $this->_sQuery = $this->_pdo->prepare($query);
            echo "<pre>";print_r($this->_sQuery);echo "</pre>"; I have result:

Comment: PDOStatement Object
(
    [queryString] => SELECT COUNT(title_pl) AS count FROM psGalleryCategories WHERE title_pl = ''';fwefewfpew'f'wef'wefew.''fewvdsniu*&&^&^@^7ef125e2'';
)

Comment: please don't post code in the comments, it's an unreadable mess. The comments should just be for brief discussion and requests for clarification. If it's relevant to the question then add it to the question (using the "edit" button just underneath the blue "php" tag) and [format it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) using the tools available. Thanks.

Comment: The field `title_pl` does seem to appear anywhere—not in the `INSERT` statement, nor in the array of parameters to be bound. Where is it coming from?

Comment: Actually... that `INSERT` is not the code that is causing the issue. The error message clearly shows a `SELECT` query. And my bet is that they are using an interpolated string with a variable; e.g: `SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar = $bar`. It should be pointed out that this is _not secure_ as you are not using prepared statements properly and are vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Instead you need to do something like: `$this->_db->query('SELECT COUNT(title_pl) AS count FROM psGalleryCategories WHERE title_pl = :title_pl', ['title_pl' => $whateverVariableYouWantToBindToThisParam])`